# How can I write a query which require parameter for SQLite with Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-room

I know I can use Code A to a accept a parameter for id

I hope to accept a `order by` parameter in Code B, how can I do?

You know there are four methods for `order by` , there are :

```
SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate desc
SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate asc
SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY title desc
SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY title asc
```

**Code A**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where id=:id")
suspend fun getByID(id:Int): RecordEntity
```

**Code B**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
fun listAll(): Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room: Order By not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240906/android-room-order-by-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways that you can do this.

- a fourth way, using CTE's, can be found at [How can I add the sencond sort item when I use CASE to require parameter for SQLite with Room in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278049/how-can-i-add-the-sencond-sort-item-when-i-use-case-to-require-parameter-for-sql/76285491#76285491)

**Option 1.**

Have 4 `@Query` annotated functions for each option and then have a 5th function that invokes the respective function of the 4 based upon parameters. *(option 3 uses an alternative numeric representation for the 4 options)*

e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
fun selectOption1(): List<RecordEntity>
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate asc")
fun selectOption2(): List<RecordEntity>
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
fun selectOption3(): List<RecordEntity>
fun selectOption4(): Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
fun selectAppropriateOption(orderColumn: String, ifASC: Boolean): Flow<List<RecordEntity>> {
    if (orderColumn.equals("createdDate"))
        if (ifASC) {
            return selectOption2()
        } else {
            return selectOption1()
        }
    if (orderColumn.equals("title"))
        if (ifASC) {
            return selectOption4()
        } else {
            return selectOption3()
        }
    /* handle neither orderColumn????? */
    return selectOption1() /* e.g. default */
}
```

**Option 2. using `@RawQuery`**

Have something along the lines of:-

```
@RawQuery
fun rq(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<RecordEntity>
fun selectViaRawQuery(orderColumn: String, ifASC: Boolean): Flow<List<RecordEntity>> {
    var orderType = " ASC "
    if (!ifASC) orderType = " DESC "
    return flow { emit(rq(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY $orderColumn $orderType"))) }
}
```

- **Noting** that Room cannot check the validity of the query at compile time and thus there is the greater chance of a run time error.

**Option 3.**

The last option is to utilise the CASE WHE THEN ELSE END construct. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75633300/room-order-by-case-where-can-i-define-the-optional-parameter/75633421#75633421) is very much the same as for your question (2 columns and both order types).

e.g.

```
@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM info_table ORDER BY " +
            "CASE WHEN :parameter = 0 THEN createdDate END DESC, " +
            "CASE WHEN :parameter = 1 THEN createdDate END ASC, " +
            "CASE WHEN :parameter = 2 THEN title END DESC, " +
            "CASE WHEN :parameter = 3 THEN title END ASC"
)
fun selectViaCase(/*childId: Int,*/ parameter: Int): Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
```

All the above have been tested (compiled and run), but on the main thread and hence no suspend or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278049/how-can-i-add-the-sencond-sort-item-when-i-use-case-to-require-parameter-for-sql ?